What exactly is a Normal shock in a CD Nozzle?
This might sound like a simple straight forward question but it is bothering me for hours now. What exactly is a normal shock in a CD Nozzle?? From various resources I came to know that a normal shock in the diverging section of a CD nozzle decelerates the flow to subsonic speeds and increases the pressure. By Newton's 2nd law, there must be force acting onto the fluid in order to decelerate it across the shock. Where is that force coming from? Certainly from the high pressure downstream to the shock. So in order for the flow to decelerate across a shock there should be a higher pressure downstream to the shock but the downstream pressure across the shock is higher because the flow is decelerated across the shock...It seems I have been stuck in a vicious cycle!!

Change in momentum is indeed produced by a force. Try blowing on your hand. What applies the force to decelerate the air? Viscosity can tie a fluid to walls too.
